# centering layout android same height

Tags: android, xml, layout

I can't upload image via imgur, so I will post link via drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Ho1o8QjLVaLWsyNmxnQTV1alU/view?usp=sharing

here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lay"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load Picture"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

what I need is to make the layout center, like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Ho1o8QjLVaWDVjWk02ckVWeEU/view?usp=sharing

please help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must add `weightSum` property to LinearLayout and set `0dp` for `android:layout_width` for image views, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load Picture"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `weight` to your vertical layouts too.

Try this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load Picture"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```